# PHP form submit updates the field pip_date everytime form is submitted after editing a user

Tags: php, forms

When for a user `$_POST['on_pip']` has value equals to `1`
it should add the current time in db by the following code :

```
// It will save the date when a user is rated PIP and removes the date when PIP rating gets removed

if ($_POST['on_pip'] == '1'){
    $_POST['pip_date'] = $this->date->now();
} else {
    $_POST['pip_date'] = null;
}

$this->Model_User->save(_request('user_id'), $_POST)
```

(I am using `radio button` here if it says yes it saves `value = 1` and if its no `value = 0`)

**My Problem :**

Suppose a user have `on_pip` value saved equals to 1. when I edit that user with on_pip value 1 and update some other details and save the user, it updates the pip_date for current time.

How can I check if value of $_POST['on_pip'] was changed on the form submit or not?

If a user already have on_pip value it should not update the pip_date

Comment: Why do you add this in else $_POST['pip_date'] = null;

Comment: it will remove the date when on_pip value changes to 0

Comment: Where is the code you use to insert values to your database?

Comment: this is inserting into db by calling save method from user model
$this->Model_User->save(_request('user_id'), $_POST);

Comment: Actually, I could not clearly understand what you want to do. Please clarify so I can help you. Is that check box value saved on the database too if it is set to 1 or 0?

Comment: I got my problem solved. And yes Sir Thanks for your concern :) :) It means a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the $_POST['on_pip'] into a $_SESSION var and then check if it has already been set in a previous request during the same user session.

For instance,

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION['pip_date_set']) || $_SESSION['pip_date_set'] == false){
        if($_POST['on_pip'] === '1'){
            $_POST['pip_date'] = $this->date->now();
            $_SESSION['pip_date_set'] = true;
        }else{
            $_POST['pip_date'] = null;
        }
    }

    //code to insert into DB...
?>
```

Or you can just store pip_date in your $_SESSION var and restrict overriding in the current session..

Like so,

```
<?php   
    if(isset($_POST['on_pip']) && $_POST['on_pip'] == '1'){
        if(!isset($_SESSION['pip_date'])){
            //pip_date has not yet been initialized during the current session, let's set it now:
            $_SESSION['pip_date'] = $this->date->now();
            $_POST['pip_date'] = $_SESSION['pip_date'];//If the pip_date is not supposed to be changed, should this exist in a $_POST var at all?
        }else{
            $_POST['pip_date'] = null;//Again, should you be using a $POST var for this?
        }
    }

    //code to insert into DB...
?>
```

Or, if you would like to prevent overriding of the date in the database altogether... you will have to do a check beforehand... or set db user permissions to prevent update on that specific field.

Hope this was what you were looking for...